# Applying nested object of attributes in Jade/Pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Is there a way to pass an object of data/aria attributes to an element?

I've tried:

```
div(data={foo:'bar'})

div(data={foo='bar'})

div&attributes({aria:{foo:'bar'}})
```

But none of these output the desired attribute notation. The first and third place an object literal in the base data/aria attribute. The second is a syntax error.

The only ways that I can find that work are:

```
div(data-foo='bar')

div&attributes({'aria-foo':'bar'})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By leading new lines with a minus `-` you are able to write regular JavaScript in JADE / PUG. This gives you a powerfull weapon to resolve almost everything.

Just grab an regular object like `var attributes = {'foo':'bar', 'bar':'foo'}` and extend the keys of it in a for each loop with your desired prefix.

Here is a working Pen http://codepen.io/pure180/pen/kXwqdA and
this could be your code:

```
- var attributes = {'foo':'bar', 'bar':'baz'}
- var ariaAttributes = {}
- for (attr in attributes) {
-     var key = 'aria-' + attr
-     ariaAttributes[key] = attributes[attr]
- }

div&attributes(ariaAttributes) Test
```

You can also use it as an global mixin, here is the Pen http://codepen.io/pure180/pen/KrqYpB and it can looks then like this:

```
mixin setAriaAttr(object)
  - var attributes = object
  - var ariaAttributes = {}
  - for (attr in attributes) {
  -     var key = 'aria-' + attr
  -     ariaAttributes[key] = attributes[attr]
  - }

  div&attributes(ariaAttributes) Test

- var aria = {'foo':'bar', 'bar':'baz'}
+setAriaAttr(aria)
```

Comment: Is there a way to override the &attributes or do this as a generic mixin? I don't want all of this logic on every template

Comment: Of course there is a way :-), this let all your dreams come true, here is a mixin Pen: http://codepen.io/pure180/pen/KrqYpB

Comment: This isn't quite generic enough. I'd want to apply it to any element. But thank you. This has gotten me far enough to take it the rest of the way.

Comment: Yeah... you are welcome... If this is not fair enough for you, you can also write a global function that resolves your work, just place it into your rootfile and it is accessible in all inherited files. If you like i can write a small how to tomorrow?!